# Menu disappears below certain screen width

Tags: html, wordpress, css, menu

I'm having problems getting my menu to display correctly under 600px on a development site of mine. The top part of the site (video area) is responsive >1024px. Everything should stay a static width below that. My menu is fine until it gets below 600px, and then it disappears completely. This happens only on the front page (inner pages have a different header).

Thanks for any help!

edit: sorry didn't link to site - http://dev.longviewsources.com/

Comment: Please add the relevant code from the site to your question. No one wants to dig through your source to find your menu HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thgat's because in your style.css file on line 510 you have

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .main-navigation ul {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

You could have found easily what's happening with Firefox inspector, it's great tool.

Comment: Aha thanks, I actually use Chrome's element inspector, but I just missed this. It's some CSS that came with the barebones theme I built this from.

Answer (score 1):

In your style.css

Find

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
```

Inside you will find

```
.main-navigation ul {
        display: none;
}
```

Remove display:none; so it will be

```
.main-navigation ul {

}
```

Then the menu won't disappear.